# Is there a word for taking a statistical model, and working backwards to the algebraic proof?

Tags: statistics, proof-writing, research, monty-hall, systems-theory

As an example, I'm trying to work backwards from the statistics generated from the [Monty Hall Problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mhlc7peGlGg) and figure out the variables and their relation to each other.

The specifics of the Monty Hall Problem aside, is there a general term for using statistics as a point of inquiry, and then using that to identify other relationships often used in systems theory?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Are you asking about situations in which you imagine that there are hidden variables which control the situation but which are not directly observable?  One class of such models are known as [Hidden Markov Models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model).

Comment: @lulu I'll read and study that, but I'm thinking more abstractly.  If statistical analysis lets me guess what's inside the black box, how can I reconstruct a black box.  The latter makes me think algebra, or hard sciences / biology physics.

Comment: Well, it's still not clear to me.  You need a model.  Absent a model, then everything could just be the output of a suitable random number generator.

Comment: Is a model the same thing as an algebraic function? @lulu Examples are welcome so I can start communicating along those lines

Comment: I am not understanding what you are asking.  If all I have is the outcome, then what's the problem?  I get outcome $i$ with probability $p_i$ and I can look for dependences and such by experiment.  Everything is described by the joint probability.  If, to the contrary, you assume that there is some underlying structure that explains things you should try to describe what that structure is.  that's a model!

Comment: Doctors face this all the time.  They see observable symptoms.  Headache, fatigue, fast pulse, etc.  They believe that there are hidden states of the body that can explain these and they need to create models that re-estimate the probability of these hidden states.  That is, my headache and fatigue might be caused by a brain tumor but is more probably explained by a poor night's sleep.  However, if you add in a dramatic change in vision (or whatever) then the probabilities might change.

Comment: For complex, interdependent systems, coming to a conclusion based on statistics is a time efficient option. However, smaller problems could be "rebuilt" from math theory and potentially give us insight into something that was overlooked. Here, I'm trying to figure out the word to describe the intellectual rigor (and approach) used to close that gap between a derived fact, and something more first degree

Comment: Is it incorrect of me to call statistics "derived facts", when another source of a more authoritative proof may exist?

Comment: Maybe if you gave a concrete instance of what you are speaking of it would help.  There are, for example, lots of instances in number theory when one works off of statistics only.  There are, for example, statistical primality tests...for cryptography these may suffice.  But nobody would mistake statistical evidence for a proof.